# IIS Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules: Rewrite and RequestRouting values in the Areas attribute (web.config)

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to trace a **Rewrite rule in IIS**. **Failed Request Tracing** is enabled and the errors are logged but I cannot have the information I would like (I have only the orginal url and not the final url when it is rewrited).

I think I should add something like this in my **web.config** :

```
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
```

but **Rewrite** and **RequestRouting** are not recognized.

What IIS propose me to add is those kind of values:

```
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
```

Here is a sample of my **web.config**

```
<tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests>
    <add path="*">
      <traceAreas>
        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
      </traceAreas>
      <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="404" />
    </add>
  </traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `ASPNET` [trace provider](http://twitpic.com/e8uttr)? Maybe the details are being logged through that?

Comment: I tried and it didn't help ...

Answer (score 0):

to add these items must download https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and reinstall rewrite_en-US.msi module
But so far this installation has managed to add only Rewrite